# Using .clear method in Ruby

Tags: ruby, methods

Couldn't explain my question succinctly enough in the title, so I'm putting it here. It will actually be easier to show the code before asking my question:

```
array1 = []
array2 = [1,2,3]

array1 = array2
#=> array1 = [1,2,3]

array2.clear

#=> array1 = []
#=> array2 = []
```

Why does using the .clear method on the second array also clear what is in the first array? I guess what I'm asking is, once we set `array1 = array2`, why is `array1` affected by the `.clear` we apply to `array2`? It seems that `array1 = array2` will hold true for the duration of my script, is this right?

In order for `array1` to remain unchanged once I do `array2.clear`, would I need to implement `array1 = array2` a different way, such as using a `for` loop and `.unshift`ing elements from `array2` and `.push`ing them over to `array1`?

Comment: Did you see this answer?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3672399/ruby-variable-array-assignment-misunderstanding-with-push-method?answertab=oldest#tab-top.  Great explanation of references.  Also, for bonus points, suggestion that you can use `.clone` to create a true copy.

Comment: Thanks for that link. I feel silly now.. can I delete my question? lol

Answer (score 7):

When you do

```
array1 = array2
```

`array1` and `array2` reference to the same `Array` object now. So any modifications you make to either will affect to the other.

```
array1.object_id
# => 2476740
array2.object_id
# => 2476740
```

See? They have the same `object_id`.

---

If this behavior is not what you expected, try

```
array1 = array2.dup
```

or

```
array1 = array2.clone
```

Comment: I think using `object_id` is the best demonstration of what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

You may be confused because with integers it *seems* like it works differently:

```
a = 6  # puts "6" into a memory location, and point "a" to it
b = a  # points "b" to the same memory location as "a"
b = 7  # puts "7" into a memory location, and point "b" to it.

puts a  # 6
puts b  # 7
```

Note that with the `=` you are telling the variable to point to an object at a certain memory address. Contrast this with your question:

```
array1 = []  # put empty array in memory and points array1 to it
array2 = [1,2,3]  # put [1,2,3] array into memory and point array2 to it

array1 = array2  # make array2 point to same location as array1
#=> array1 = [1,2,3] 

array2.clear  # tell ruby to clear the memory location pointed to by array2 (uh oh, array1 pointing to same place!)
```