# In Ruby, How can I un-link two arrays?

Tags: arrays, ruby

Say I have

```
x=[1,2,3]
```

and I make
`y=x`

if I do
`y.delete_at(0)`
then y becomes [2,3] as well as x, which surprised me. I want to set y equals to x but then whatever I do to y, shouldn't affect the original array that is x.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using .clear method in Ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30315197/using-clear-method-in-ruby)

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
y = x.dup
```

This is how the assignment operator works in ruby:

```
x -------------> [1, 2, 3]

x = y

x -------------> [1, 2, 3]
                 ^
                 |
y ---------------+
```

That's because `x` stores the address in memory where the Array `[1, 2, 3]` is located.  Let's say that address is `123 Maple Street`.  When you assign `x` to `y`, then `y's` value is also `123 Maple Street`.  Then, if you tell `y` to demolish one of the bedrooms at her address, then when x glances at his address he also will see a demolished bedroom.

Answer (score 2):

Using **`.dup`**

```
> x = [1,2,3]
 => [1, 2, 3] 
> y = x.dup
 => [1, 2, 3] 
> y.delete_at(0)
 => 1 
> y
 => [2, 3] 
> x
 => [1, 2, 3]
```

Using **`.clone`**

```
 > y = x.clone
 => [1, 2, 3] 
 > y.delete_at(0)
 => 1 
 > y
 => [2, 3] 
 > x
 => [1, 2, 3]
```

---

**.dup** and **.colne** Both looks similar, Isn't it?

They both create a shallow copy of an object (meaning that they don't copy the objects that might be referenced within the copied object). However, `#clone` does two things that `#dup` doesn't:

- copy the singleton class of the copied object
- maintain the frozen status of the copied object

### Examples of the singleton methods not being copied.

Using **`.dup`**

```
a = Object.new
def a.foo; :foo end
p a.foo
# => :foo
b = a.dup
p b.foo
# => undefined method `foo' for #<Object:0x007f8bc395ff00> (NoMethodError)
```

Now let's see for **`.clone`**

```
a = Object.new
def a.foo; :foo end
p a.foo
# => :foo
b = a.clone
p b.foo
# => :foo
```

### Frozen state:

```
a = Object.new
a.freeze
p a.frozen?
# => true
b = a.dup
p b.frozen?
# => false
c = a.clone
p c.frozen?
# => true
```

I hope now these things make you clear to understand. :) Reference taken from coderwall

Answer (score -1):

Ruby works with references. To create a copy, try either one of this

```
y= x.dup
```

or

```
y= x.clone
```